# Which is the best way to create json objects in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to create json objects in swift with dictionaries, but the code is getting longer and longer. Is there any way to reduce the lines of for example this code? You can see that both dictionaries are the same except the "id" field
If it's possible without using external libraries

```
var product:  [String: String] = [
            "chemical_id":String(activity.chemical!.id),
            "plague_id":String(activity.plague!.id),
            "justification":activity.justification!,
            "amount":activity.amount!,
            "amount_scope":activity.amount_scope!,
            "security_time":activity.security_time!,
            "effectiveness": activity.effectiveness!
        ]
        if activity.id != -1 {
            product = [
                "id":String(activity.id),
                "chemical_id":String(activity.chemical!.id),
                "plague_id":String(activity.plague!.id),
                "justification":activity.justification!,
                "amount":activity.amount!,
                "amount_scope":activity.amount_scope!,
                "security_time":activity.security_time!,
                "effectiveness": activity.effectiveness!
            ]
        }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. These are just regular Swift dictionaries.

Comment: you may consider checking first if the id is not equal to -1 to add the id key to the product dictionary, then you add the other keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it on the condition

```
if activity.id != -1 {
    product["id"] = String(activity.id)
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!